# transfer character in function to the function in r

Tags: r, function

I have such a problem, I want to define the grad function as an input of the function. Please see the example below.

```
f<-function(grad="2*m-4"){
y=grad
return(y)
}
f(3)=2
```

Comment: You're saying that you don't want to hard-code `y <- 2*m - 4` in the function, instead make the *expression* an argument to the `f` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm usually not a fan of using `eval(parse(text=..))`, but it does do this with a character string:

```r
f <- function(m, grad="2*m-4"){
  eval(parse(text = grad))
}
f(3)
# [1] 2
```

The two take-aways:

- if your `grad` formula requires variables, you should make them arguments of your `f`unction; and
- `parse(text=..)` parse the string as if the user typed it in to R's interpreter, and it returns an *expression*:

  ```r
  parse(text="2*m - 4")
  # expression(2*m - 4)
  ```

  This expression can then be evaluated with `eval`.

Comment: can you look at my other question which is about NN and optimizer please?

Comment: I'm not proficient in NN, sorry.